# How to pass the value correctly on a function's param that use string literal import path?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Suppose I have a file structure like this:

```
/root
  |--foo.js
  |--path
  |     |--to
  |         |utils
  |              |--translation.js
  |
  |--path
        |--to
            |--dictionary
                 |--en.json
                 |--de.json
                 |--fr.json
```

I created a function which is used to import different translation files, an put it somewhere in the project folder:

```js
// ./path/to/utils/translation.js
export const loadTranslationFiles = (pathname) => {
  ["en", "de", "fr"].forEach(async (lang) => {
    const translationValue = (await import(`${pathname}/${lang}.json`)).default;

    // ...
  })
};
```

And this function is used by `foo.js`

```js
// ./foo.js
import { loadTranslationFiles } from "./utils/translation";

loadTranslationFiles("./path/to/dictionany"); // Error: cannot file module ...
loadTranslationFiles("../../../path/to/dictionany"); // Worked!
```

The problem is: The value that I pass to `loadTranslationFiles` must be followed by the relative path of `./path/to/utils/translation.js` instead of `./foo.js`. This will make a confusion if someone reuse this function.

Is there any way that I can pass the value `./path/to/dictionany` into `loadTranslationFiles` on `./foo.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Although i would suggest you to use proper npm package that helps you manage translations.

Some popular libs are

- https://formatjs.io/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-translate

Still back to question, Instead of passing path why not just path file name!.

```
export const getTranslationPath = (language) => {
  const languageFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "../lang/dict/" + language);
  const translationValue = (await import(languageFilePath)).default;
};
```

app.jsx or tsx

```
getTranslationPath('en.json')
```